# Inherit from Python's and override __str__

Tags: python, inheritance, overriding

I am interested in doing something similar to what Django is doing to lists, e.g:

#### In django shell

```
In [4]: from TimePortal.models import Rules

In [5]: Rules.objects.all()
Out[5]: [<Rules: day_limit>]
```

I tried doing the following:

```
class TimeEntryList(list):

    def __str__(self):
        return ';'.join([str(i) for
                        i in self.__getslice__(0, self.__len__())])
```

Which seems to work in a normal Python shell:

```
In [54]: a=TimeEntryList(('1-2','2-3'))
In [58]: print a
1-2;2-3

In [59]: str(a)
Out[59]: '1-2;2-3'
```

However in my application a `TimeEntryList` instance is really a list of `TimeEntry` objects defined like this:

```
class TimeEntry(object):

    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        #self.duration = (self.end - self.start).seconds / 3600.0

    @property
    def duration(self):
        return (self.end - self.start).seconds / 3600.0

    @duration.setter
    def duration(self, value):
        self._duration = value

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {} '.format(dt.strftime(self.start, '%H:%M'),
                                 dt.strftime(self.end, '%H:%M'),)
```

When I am printing a single entry everything is ok:

```
>>> print checker.entries[0]
08:30 - 11:00
```

When I try slicing, results are different:

```
>>>print self.entries[0:2]
[<TimePortal.semantikCheckers.TimeEntry object at 0x93c7a6c>, <TimePortal.semantikCheckers.TimeEntry object at 0x93d2a4c>]
```

#### my question is:

How do I inherit from list, and define `__str__` so that print only slices works the following is output when issuing `print self.entries[0:2]`:

```
['08:30 - 11:00 ', '11:00 - 12:30 ']
```

I know this gives the desired out:

```
[str(i) for i in self.entries[:2]]
```

However my purpose here is learning a new technique and not necessarily working with what I already know.

Comment: `__repr__ = __str__; __unicode__ = __str__`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override `__repr__` of `TimeEntry` (instead of changing the list implementation). You can find an explanation about the difference between `__repr__` and `__str__` here:

[Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: Thanks! just to mention, I did override `__repr__` of `TimeEntriesList` but the solution was to override also `__repr__` of `TimeEntry`!